# Why just don't execute evaluate in CasperJS?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

There is a problem with CasperJS. Everything works until the moment I want to fill a page of text. Write all code:

```
phantom.casperPath = 'path\\to\\casperjs';
phantom.injectJs(phantom.casperPath + '\\bin\\bootstrap.js');

var url = "someurl";
var someText = "text";

var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ['jquery.min.js']
});

casper.start(url, function(){
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
    this.wait(3000, function() {
        this.click('div.but');
    });
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.evaluate(function(){ //сюда не заходит
        document.querySelector("div.anotherElem").innerHTML = someText;
    });
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.capture('screen.png', {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: 1280,
        height: 1024
    });
});
```

The function evaluate just does not execute. Use the latest version CasperJS, which integrates into PhantomJS (v1.8). Who used casper, tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How do you check whether it executes or not? Are you taking a screenshot or are you reading the page content? Please provide a complete and minimal script that demonstrates your problem. You can [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: @ArtjomB. i put `console.log('something');` inside evaluate and didn't see it after executing in the command line

Comment: @ArtjomB., writed all code, help pls :)

Comment: 1. So what does the screenshot show? 2. If you want to receive console messages from the page context, then you need to listen to the "remote.message" event. 3. Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.